# RegularExpressions in WPF

Tags: c#, regex

I know there are already some kind of posts, that try to explain the RegEx-string. but i still don't get it. In my case, I need a regex for a WPF, that only allows "Numeric-Keyboard". Its here in the Code:

```
private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
  Regex regex = new Regex("[-+]?[0-9]*,?[0-9]*");
  e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
}
```

so here are some example-numbers, i need to allow:
"1" or "-1" or "-0,5" or "4,00" or "-3,56" or "3,3" or

" '-2, ' as '-2,0' or '-2' "

(so its all between -4 to +4. There can be a comma, But it don't have to be. If there s a comma, it needs one or 2 digits behind - not more. It should also be a "," not a "." - this is important)
Does anybody know how to write this RegEx-String? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking it down, what you are after is not that complicated.

First off, your maximum/minimum range is from -4 up till 4. Taking into consideration the decimal section, you can have the following: `^[+-]?4(,0{1,2})?$`. So in here, we expect a `+` or a `-` (optionally), the number 4, optionally followed by a comma and one or two 0's.

In your case, we now need to match the middle of your range, that is, from -3.99 up till 3.99. This can be achieved as follows: `^[+-]?[0-3](,\d{1,2})?$`. In this case, we are also expecting a `+` or a `-` (optionally). We then expect to match a digit, between 0 and 3, optionally followed by a comma and 1 or 2 digits.

Combining them, we end up with something like so: `^[+-]?((4(,0{1,2})?)|([0-3](,\d{1,2})?))$`. Example available [here](https://regex101.com/r/wleQZZ/1).

EDIT:
As per the comments, you need to *escape* the slash in front of the `\d`, because the C# compiler will try and find a special meaning for `\d`, just like it does when you do `\n`, or `\t`. The easiest way is to use the `@` character, so that the C# compiler threats the string as a literal: `Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[+-]?((4(,0{1,2})?)|([0-3](,\d{1,2})?))$");`.

Comment: Hey, thanks this sounds "easy" but: in Visual Studio there is a failure at ",\d" and it sais: CS1009  C# Unrecognized escape sequence... it happens everytime i added something with a backslash in regex... i don´t know why, i m even using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Comment: The \ defines an escape sequence, try \\ or a verbatim string literal (`@"regex"`)

Comment: with \\ at least there´s no error anymore, but it´s like: nothing happend, you can tip in everything you want:

Comment: Regex regex = new Regex("^[+-]?((4(,0{1,2})?)|([0-3](,\\d{1,2})?))$");
this way and              Regex regex = new Regex("[^[+-]?((4(,0{1,2})?)|([0-3](,\\d{1,2})?))$]"); this way

Comment: `[^[+-]?((4(,0{1,2})?)|([0-3](,\\d{1,2})?))$]` is a different regex and does not what you intend to do. The Regex npinti provided is correct, so the problem lies not within the regex itself, rather in your Event-Handling (which is a different question).

Comment: i guess this is it.. but for example: regex("[^0-9]+"); does work (only numbers between 0-9)

Comment: @SKirchner: I have updated my answer. Can you please check again?

Comment: i found the update aswell, but you can still type a z or a 5 for example :/

Comment: @SKirchner: I do not know when is your event fired to be honest. That being said, the expression shouldn't allow anything else.

Comment: @SKirchner: I can only guess, but i see 2 things which may produce the wrong behavior: 1. The `e.Text` does not contain all the characters, only the "new" ones (like `3`, then `,` `9` etc.). 2. The `e.handled` should only be set to `True` when you don' t want to accept the "fresh" Input (maybe something like this `e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch(NumberValidationTextBox.Text + e.Text);`) and not when it is matching the Regex (which is a valid Input).

Comment: @npinit: its fired in xaml-file: <Textbox PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationTextBox" /> like this

Comment: if i do it like this:             Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[+-]?((4(,0{1,2})?)|([0-3](,\d{1,2})?))$");
          e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch(e.Text);   i can type in 0-4 (which is good), but no , and no - or +

Comment: @SKirchner: As i expected. Now consider Point 1. in my previous Answer: When you press a Key, this will be passed to your Event as "Input". This means your `e.Text` does **only contain the pressed Key not the whole `Text`**. So the regex matches only the number `4` but not the `+ -` and therefore only accepts `4` to be entered. I suggest you to ask a new Question for this specific Problem, because we're drifting away from the original question.

Comment: ah i guess i know what you mean, but my english is not that good, so would it be possible that you can whrite the "new" question and sent me the link to ist, so i can read? would be very nice

Comment: bit if it s easyer, we can say we only want from -3,99 to 3,99 -so without any 4|0-3

Comment: You can ask the Question and i will edit and try to answer it. And don't worry about the link, the Question will be listed in your Profile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184679/discussion-between-littlebit-and-s-kirchner).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of online sites for testing regular expressions, that will break down the match string and provide an explanation for each element, e.g. https://regex101.com/

In your case, you need

```
optional '+' or '-'
either
    a group consisting of 
        '4' 
        optionally followed by a group consisting of 
            ',' and one or two '0'
or 
    a group consisting of  
        one character from '0' .. '3'   
        optionally followed by a group consisting of 
            ',' and one or two characters from '0' to '9'


[+-]?(?:(?:4(?:,0{1,2})?)|(?:[0-3](?:,[0-9]{1,2})?))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "-3,5;10;8.5;0;2;3.5;1,5";
string pattern = @"^-?[0-4](,\d{1,2})?$";
foreach(var num in s.Split(";"))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Num: {num}, Matches: {Regex.IsMatch(num, pattern)}");
}
```